# Is there a better way to rank random small data sets?

Tags: algorithm, ranking

If there is a better place to post this, please let me know before bashing me!

Explanation:
I need to create a ranking algorithm for a set of data. The issue I am facing is that the data set is not constant, it is based off of a search that will only return 100 results at a time. I have no real exposure to data science so i'm not sure what is the best practice in this situation.

Background:
From what I researched, using something like a z-score & std dev wouldn't be a good practice because the range of the data and the data is always going to vary. For Example data set one might give a result a 95%, but in another it would be 50%..
I have tried to see how baseball teams are ranked and other sports, or even ranking algorithm for search engines

A loose example:
Rank a franchised coffee shops performance in a different cities. Performance is based off how long the shop has been open, the yearly net sales, and how many cups of coffee are sold per month.

Currently what i am doing is giving each value a max potential, and based on a hardcoded range, it gets somewhere between 50-100% of that potential score. The highest possible score would be 100.

Company A = {
years_in_business: 5,
year_net_sales: 100000,
cupJoe_per_month: 1501
}
Company B ={
years_in_business: 3,
year_net_sales: 150000,
cupJoe_per_month: 2051
}
Company C ={
years_in_business: 10,
year_net_sales: 150000,
cupJoe_per_month: 1300
}

Comment: This is very vague. Do you already know how to aggregate the different objectives "yearly net sales", "cups of coffee sold per month", etc?

Comment: @Stef appreciate the comment. I apologize for being vague, I tried to share as much as I could. I am collecting the data into arrays and then performing whatever I need on them.  Just not sure how I can rank them based off of these values which are comparable

Comment: Perhaps include an example, with 5 or 6 rows of data, and explain the problem when ranking this example?

Comment: "Is there a better way to rank.." .. better that which method?

Comment: @p._phidot_ I am using a weight system. I mentioned that at the end. Does that help?

Comment: (imho) 'better' is relative. Weight system works great. But what (i meant) is.. 'better' in term of.. what? I had worked with KPI (key performance index) before.. and my personal take is, the management(boss) need to be sure of what is their their definition of  [ best ]..  Is just the best revenue = the best cafe?

Comment: "how long the shop has been open, the yearly net sales, and how many cups of coffee are sold per month." is the example of performance defined. | But how to quantify : "the a 5 year old cafe is better than 10 year old cafe", "Assuming the same cafe capacity, does the sales ratio better?", "Assuming some cafe is located near a busy subway, does the sale comparable to the one located in tourist area?" | In all these 3 cases, the original data may have to be weighted differently. (If it was me, I'll dig in the sale history for a base trendline/weightage..)

Comment: Don't worry, ranking algorithm is (for me) an art. Just rank all u want for a start, then get the feedbacks.. n try again. | afaik, no shortcut. Just (present) honest data (trends/visualization/rank), and (hopefully the boss will) gain worthy insight.

Comment: @p._phidot_ Thank you so much! They are satisfied with what i am currently doing, but I wanted to see if there was something better.

Comment: U may always suggest online (via meeting) or offline (pantry talk).. management should be all ears.. | actionable data is management priority.. but more importantly, as a data wrangler, get involve/toKnow more about how a cafe works (in the backend/ operation at site) may help to 'squeeze' out the minute detail (data that has been there, but not seen) we've missed. | similarly.. wrangling does has it's own wisdom (eg.. https://towardsdatascience.com/3-visualizations-that-changed-my-life-554b7f83e473) good luck